# Storing Polynomials using a double[] array?

Tags: java, object

This is my first post here. I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around this problem.

I am providing an array of doubles and I need to store them into a polynomial object so that I can perform a variety of polynomial operations using these values.

Example:

```
double[] coefficients = { 7, 8, -10, 2, 4 };
Polynomial polynomial1 = new Polynomial(coefficients);
```

I'm kind of lost because I have no idea what to do with the values I have... How do I store them so that the methods which perform the mathematical operations can access them along with the degree of their respective polynomials? I'm pretty new to objects, so please go easy on me!

Comment: You don't need the coefficients any more, but the operations that the class Polynomial offers, for example: polynomial1.differentiate().

Comment: What polynomial does the array in your example represent?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what the problem is.  You create a class called `Polynomial` with a field called `coefficients`

The IDE filled in all this code.  I didn't have to write anything it is so trivial

```
public class Polynomial {
    private final double[] coefficients;

    public Polynomial(double[] coefficients) {
        this.coefficients = coefficients;
    }
}
```